# Search String Not properly passed

Tags: c#

my code is as below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string startPath = @"c:\Temp\att\";
        string xmlpath = @"c:\Temp\log\";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(xmlpath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".xml"));

        foreach (string xml in files)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xml);
            XmlNodeList Xe = doc.SelectNodes("//FileDump/Message/Attachment");
            var Message_ID = doc.SelectSingleNode("//FileDump/Message/MsgID").InnerXml;
            foreach (XmlNode Xn in Xe)
            {
                var linkNode = Xn.SelectSingleNode("FileName");
                if (linkNode != null)
                {
                    string link = linkNode.InnerText.Trim();
                }
                string File_Name = Xn.SelectSingleNode("FileName").InnerXml;
                string File_ID = Xn.SelectSingleNode("FileID").InnerXml;


                //System.IO.File.Copy(curFile, msgsave, true);

                string msgsave = @"c:\Temp\ZIP\" + File_Name;
                string curFile = startPath + File_Name;
                string bbgfile = xmlpath + "MR_" + Message_ID + ".xml";
                string zipfilename = "MR_" + Message_ID + ".zip";
                string rkzip = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\log\", zipfilename);

                try
                {

                    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                    {
                        string zipFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\log\",  "MR_" + Message_ID + ".zip");
                        zip.AddFile(curFile, "");
                        zip.AddFile(bbgfile, "");
                        zip.Save(rkzip);
                    }

                }
```

the issue is as follow:
 the FileName has more then one file and it only zips one file, I tried debugging my code and it shows 3 files however only one file is zipped. 
can someone outline what is wrong with my code?
FileName is an indicator of the attachment files in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will only see write for the last line because your are creating a new zip file and overwriting the previous time.   You need to move the creation and saving of the zip file to outside of your `foreach (XmlNode Xn in Xe)` or open the existing zip file using [ZipFile.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485716.aspx) and update it.

Comment: it still does not work it only copies the first file and skips the rest: string msgsave = @"c:\Temp\ZIP\" + doc.SelectSingleNode("//FileDump/Message/Attachment/FileName").InnerXml;

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string startPath = @"c:\Temp\att\";
        string xmlpath = @"c:\Temp\log\";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(xmlpath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".xml"));

        foreach (string xml in files)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xml);
            XmlNodeList Xe = doc.SelectNodes("//FileDump/Message/Attachment");
            var Message_ID = doc.SelectSingleNode("//FileDump/Message/MsgID").InnerXml;
            foreach (XmlNode Xn in Xe)
            {
                var linkNode = Xn.SelectSingleNode("FileName");
                if (linkNode != null)
                {
                    string link = linkNode.InnerText.Trim();
                }
                string File_Name = Xn.SelectSingleNode("FileName").InnerXml;
                string File_ID = Xn.SelectSingleNode("FileID").InnerXml;

                //System.IO.File.Copy(curFile, msgsave, true);

            }
            try
            {
                string msgsave = @"c:\Temp\ZIP\" + doc.SelectSingleNode("//FileDump/Message/Attachment/FileName").InnerXml;
                string curFile = startPath + doc.SelectSingleNode("//FileDump/Message/Attachment/FileName").InnerXml;
                string bbgfile = xmlpath + "MR_" + Message_ID + ".xml";
                string zipfilename = "MR_" + Message_ID + ".zip";
                string rkzip = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\log\", zipfilename);

                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    string zipFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\log\", "MR_" + Message_ID + ".zip");
                    zip.AddFile(curFile, "");
                    zip.AddFile(bbgfile, "");
                    zip.Save(rkzip);
                }

            }
```

even though I took the zip outside foreach loop it sill zips only the first FileName even though there are 3 FilName